# How to move the first instance of a string in a column so it's before that string's group?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a single column like the below:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Level = c(
    'Midwest',
    'Wisconsin: Good',
    'Wisconsin: Neutral',
    'Wisconsin: Bad',
    NA,
    'Minnesota: Good',
    'Minnesota: Neutral',
    'Minnesota: Bad',
    NA,
    'New England',
    'New Hampshire: Good',
    'New Hampshire: Neutral',
    'New Hampshire: Bad',
    NA,
    'Vermont: Good',
    'Vermont: Neutral',
    'Vermont: Bad'
  )
)
```

I'm interested in doing two things to this column:

1. Grab the first instance of the `Good` level for each state and place it in a new row about the `Good` level, and...
2. Remove the state names from each level so it just shows `Good`, `Neutral`, and `Bad` below each state name.

The result would look like this:

```
df_desired <- data.frame(
  Level = c(
    'Midwest',
    'Wisconsin',
    'Good',
    'Neutral',
    'Bad',
    NA,
    'Minnesota',
    'Good',
    'Neutral',
    'Bad',
    NA,
    'New England',
    'New Hampshire',
    'Good',
    'Neutral',
    'Bad',
    NA,
    'Vermont',
    'Good',
    'Neutral',
    'Bad'
  )
)
```

What's the best way to go about achieving this using R, ideally using `dplyr` if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way in `tidyverse` - Extract the prefix part before the `:` in 'Level' with `str_extract`, then split the 'Level' column at the `:` with `separate_rows`, remove the `duplicated` elements and remove the prefix column 'new'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
out <- df %>%
     mutate(new = str_extract(Level, "\\w+(?=:)")) %>% 
     separate_rows(Level, sep = ":\\s*") %>% 
     filter(!duplicated(cur_data()) | is.na(Level)) %>%
     select(-new)
```

-checking with OP's desired

```
> all.equal(out, df_desired, check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this, but to account for character columns to the right of this Level column? Right now when I plug in this code for a wider dataset, the `duplicated(cur_data())` piece doesn't perform as expected due to the extra columns. (I recognize this is different than my initial ask, but I'm wondering if there's  a way to make its use case more broad.)

Comment: @NatashaR. in that case, just do `filter(!duplicated(tibble(Level, new))|is.na(Level))`